# Replicate Yelp star review widget

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to replicate the star rating widget on yelp.com - 5 star rating widget that as you hover over the next star, all previous stars change color to match the active star. Also need a hover state that displays a description for the star rating.

You can see the widget in action here:
https://www.yelp.com/writeareview/biz/C5SIHa89RV4Gw05zD8vLQg?return_url=%2Fwriteareview%2Fsearch%3Fwar_desc%3Dtacos%26war_loc%3DAustin%252C%2BTX

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Seems like less of "trying" and more "wishing" :-p. Show us some code - what is not working as expected?

Comment: Have you inspected their HTML? Have you found the CSS, have you seen this image? https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/367f0663a441/ico/stars/v2/stars_map_30x30.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

made up something without JS here's the result:

```css
.stars{
  displaY:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.stars span{
  color:#999;
  displaY:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.stars>span:hover:after{
  position:absolute;
  content: attr(title);
  left:100%;
}

.stars>span:nth-child(1):hover,
.stars>span:nth-child(1):hover ~ span{color: red;}
.stars>span:nth-child(2):hover,
.stars>span:nth-child(2):hover ~ span{color: #f73;}
.stars>span:nth-child(3):hover,
.stars>span:nth-child(3):hover ~ span{color: #fa2;}
.stars>span:nth-child(4):hover,
.stars>span:nth-child(4):hover ~ span{color: #eb2;}
.stars>span:nth-child(5):hover,
.stars>span:nth-child(5):hover ~ span{color: #d92;}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <span title="WOW">&#9733;</span>
  <span title="LOL">&#9733;</span>
  <span title="Yey">&#9733;</span>
  <span title="Hmm">&#9733;</span>
  <span title="Boo">&#9733;</span>
</div>
```

Now in JS or jQuery you only need to assign an `active` class and submit the vote to the server (like in this ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vopuho/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***).

**EDIT:**

Since the above can be a bit buggy ("thanks" to CSS) here's a mostly JS (jQuery) example:

```js
var msg = ["Hover and Click to rate!","Boo","Hmm","Yey","LOL","WOW"];

$("[data-stars]").each(function(){
  
  var $el = $(this);
  var h   = $el.height();
  var w   = $el.width();
  var old = $el.data("stars");
  var now;
  var $info = $("<span/>");  
  $el.append($info);

  function setStars( val ){
    $el.attr("data-stars", val);
    $info.text( msg[val] );
  }
  setStars( old );
  
  $el.on("mousemove", function(e){
    now = (e.pageX-$(this).offset().left)/w*5 +1|0;
    setStars( now );
  }).on("mouseleave", function(){
    setStars( old );
  }).on("click", function(){
    old = now;
    setStars( old );
    // Submit `old` string value ("1-5") to server using AJAX 
  });
  
});
```

```css
[data-stars]{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;
  height:30px;
  width:150px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpQ8g.png) 0 0 / cover;
}
[data-stars]>span{
  position:absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
  left:100%;
  top:9px;
}
[data-stars="0"]{background-position:0    0px;}
[data-stars="1"]{background-position:0  -30px;}
[data-stars="2"]{background-position:0  -60px;}
[data-stars="3"]{background-position:0  -90px;}
[data-stars="4"]{background-position:0 -120px;}
[data-stars="5"]{background-position:0 -150px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-stars=0></div><br>
<div data-stars=2></div><br>
<div data-stars=5></div><br>
<div data-stars=4></div>
```

Comment: this is absolutely brilliant! Exactly what I am looking to do... I will paste my final code when done. Only question I have is - how do I set the RemoveClass attribute to the span so that if a user wants to "reset" their vote or select another vote it doesn't add the class to every span?

Comment: So in order to store the value in the database i created a hidden input form and then added a custom attribute called rating to the rating span. Using JS i passed the attribute to the input field:


`$(".stars span").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    document.getElementById('review_rating').value = ($(this).attr("rating"));
});`

Comment: @stankobrin see this demo: http://jsbin.com/vopuho/2/edit?html,css,js,output - you need to remove the `active` class from siblings. To get the 1,2,3,4,5 rating use `5 - index`.

Comment: Works amazingly but obv on hover it's still a bit buggy. Looks like it needs to somehow remove the siblings on hover too. On click it's perfect!

Comment: @stankobrin yes, I've noticed that, the active class is fighting with the CSS to get the proper hover color. I'll show you another solution soon

Comment: @roko-c-buljan the alternative works great.. two questions though:
1. how would i pass the [data-stars] property to my input box. I've tried this but no luck:
`document.getElementById('review_rating').value =  $el.attr("[data-stars]");`

2. is it possible to include an image along side the "var msg"?

Comment: ok i sorted out part 1: `document.getElementById('review_rating').value = $el.attr("data-stars");` on the click method worked for storing the value.

Comment: Take a look at the code. The variable old holds the new value. The value is a string integer from 1 to 5

Comment: @stankobrin yes, you can pass an image: instead of `.text(` use `.html(` and inside the `msg` array use standard HTML image tag. See? http://jsbin.com/waqafe/2/edit?html,css,js,output. Please if you have other questions you can use this code and ask a [new] question (Cause we're getting a bit offtopic here ;) ).